# Cruft in swagger_yard OpenAPI.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, openapi

I'm using swagger_yard with an API that's never been previously documented. In the OpenAPI.yml, most of the model and controller fields `summary` and `description` are prepended with something like `!ruby/string:YARD::Docstring`. These are interfering with our automated documentation site parsing and will probably also interfere with our SDK generation.

My codebase documentation looks like:

```
# This endpoint returns account blah blah taco.
#
# @path [GET] users/somestuff
# @response_type [Account] 
def index
   @accounts ||= ::stuff
end
```

The output in the OpenApi.yml for that code block looks like:

```
summary: !ruby/string:YARD::Docstring 'This endpoint returns blah blah taco.'
```

How do I keep these from showing up in my OAS?

I am using swagger_yard with an RoR API codebase. There are thousands of lines in the OAS that interfere with parsing. The lines in the OAS look like:

```
!ruby/string:YARD::Docstring
&3 !ruby/object:YARD::CodeObjects::ModuleObject
!ruby/array:YARD::CodeObjects::CodeObjectList
object: &1244 !ruby/object:YARD::CodeObjects::MethodObject
```